# What does ' : : after ' mean in my CSS targeting a bar in WordPress, and how can I move it?

Tags: css

I need help moving a bar that highlights some post test. I found the div that is being nested in, but whenever I go try to look for the specific CSS that targets the bar I keep coming to a line that reads " : : after ". I don't know what this means or how to approach it, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I tried adjusting the css targeting the " : : after " tag to see if it could shift the entire block down but I'm not able to move it at all or target it.

Comment: "::after" it is a pseudo element. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after